# i can't find the error in my query with the column name in a php var

Tags: php, mysql

I got the column name from this query:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table
```

and I need to delete a ROW with a specific value in a column that I got from the first query:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","database");
if(isset($_POST['sup'])){

    if(mysqli_connect_error()){
        echo "Failed connection";exit;
    }
    $table=$_POST['table_sup'];
$requet = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$requet);
if(!$result){
    echo "requete incorrecte";
}
$j=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   $monChamps=$row["Field"];
   $row1[$j]=$monChamps."<br>";
    $j++;
}


$champ1=$_POST['champ_sup'];
$id=$row1[0];
$requet1="DELETE FROM $table  WHERE $id='$champ1'";
if(mysqli_query($con,$requet1)){
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("supprimer")';
    echo '</script>';
}}
```

Comment: And what gives you this query?

Comment: There's no enough code to help you with your problem.  please provide more details

Comment: hey , thanks for your intention  ,and the problem is :I don't know where to use simple quotes and back quotes and double quotes

Comment: Show us your php code please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Comment: You should not have single quotes around `$table` or `$id`

Comment: in the second query the $id that represent the column name is not working so the mysqli_query returns true but nothing happened

Comment: i just edit the post so here is the full code

Comment: hey someone helps!!!!! i still need help here!!!! @Nick !!!

Comment: Your `$id` value has a `<br>` on the end of it (`$row1[$j]=$monChamps."<br>"; $id=$row1[0];`), maybe that is causing the query to not match anything?

Comment: my god @nick thats exactly what is doing every thing wrong thank you so much